# How to block/restrict browser-based download plugins on website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I do not have any videos or music files on my website, whether YouTube, other embedded flash videos, or anything else. My website is only HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery and PHP.

The IDM (Internet Download Manager) plugin shows up at least once in a page, which tends to download the page itself as an HTML or PHP.

[image]

That is really annoying and I want to block this plugin from appearing in any section of the page. The simple solution is to remove it from FireFox, but I want to block it because I can't force users that have this plugin to remove it.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to restrict it? They can get your HTML a multitude of ways.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent your client-side code from being downloaded (you can't) or are you saying this plugin incorrectly identifies your site as a source of videos, and you wish to prevent that?